# Disable lock screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

How do I prevent my iPhone from giving me the "slide to unlock" screen every time I turn it on?

In other words, when I hit the lock or home buttons, I want to be taken straight to the homescreen, without having to "slide to unlock".

Comment: You've got two good answers. Does either explain how to do what you ask?

Answer (score 13):

Apple didn't program a way to eliminate the “Slide to unlock” screen. Without jailbreaking the phone, you can't get around this preventative feature.

(I guess the rationale behind this design is as a precaution against accidentally doing something unwanted while your phone sits in your pocket/purse/hand and the power button gets bumped. This also is how the lock screen is designed to work when the device is not powered off.)

The best you can do with a stock OS is to disable auto-locking in “Settings > General > Auto-Lock > Never”. However, whenever the phone is locked manually you will have to slide to unlock before using the device.

Answer (score 7):

If you're JailBroken, you can use [NoLockScreen](http://modmyi.com/cydia/com.openhebrew.nolockscreen). I've used it myself, and it's pretty awesome. It gets rid of the repetitive lock screen and takes you straight back to whatever you were doing before.